# what does "other" mean in Java?

Tags: java, object, interface, comparable

I have this code, but I fail to understand what "other" actually is, and what it's trying to do.

```
public interface Comparable<T>
{
    int compareTo(T other);
}
```

What does the parameter "other" suppose to mean?

Comment: It isn't a keyword, it is just word to use when you are comparing 2 things.

Compare "THIS" with the "OTHER"

Comment: It's a parameter name. You can rename it the way you wish - say, `longDescriptiveNameNumber32214`.

Comment: The term for it is "identifier", seeing how no one has mentioned it yet.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes, that is the term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a parameter name, not a keyword. It's the other value you're comparing "this" value to. So suppose you're comparing two people, you might have:

```
Person fred = new Person(...);
Person george = new Person(...);
int result = fred.compareTo(george);
```

It would be up to the `compareTo` method to compare `fred` and `george` (which it would know as `this` and `other`) by whatever means it deemed appropriate, e.g. age, name etc.

Comment: just another little question, why did you put int result? What's the answer you're expecting to get when you compared those two person? and thanks

Comment: @FuzzX: Well as I said, it depends on how `Person.compareTo` is implemented - it might compare them based on name, or based on age, or something else. It's whatever ordering is appropriate for the type.

Comment: @FuzzX The [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) of the `compareTo` method of interface `Comparable` explains what the value means that your implementation of this method must return.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a keyword, it's a parameter name that indicates the purpose of the parameter. An implementation of the interface can call the parameter the same thing or use a different name, so really in an interface it's just an FYI.

In this case it's for comparing an object with an*other* object, so that parameter is the *other* to compare against.

Answer (score 1):

It's a parameter with the type is T, don't be confused with meaning of the word

Answer (score 0):

It's not a keyword but a parameter passed to compareTo method. It just means that another object of type T which will be compared with object that invoked `compareTo` method.

So for Example, if you have class Person, with id, name and you want to compare two person with id, you could do something like:

```
 Person person1 = new Person(1, "abc");//Assume Person implements Comparable
 Person person2 = new Person(2, "pqr");
 person1.compareTo(person2);
```

So here person2 is the other object that you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The word `other` is not a keyword; rather, it is the name of a parameter. In Java, methods take `parameters`, which have the following syntax:

```
[final] Type name
```

So a method could look like this:

```
int compareTo(Object other) {}
```

where the method returns an `int`, and takes one argument of type `Object` called `other`. Inside the method, you can refer to the `Object` `other`. To call this method, you would use the following syntax:

```
compareTo(new Object());
```

A parameter, like local variables and fields, can be `final`, but not `transient` or `volatile`.